# Making a dynamic table

Tags: output-formatting, table

Given the data below:

```
ClearAll[centralityTable,community];
centralityTable={{"segw", 5, 0.583333, 0.306122, 0.0345883}, {"min", 8, 25.5, 
  0.517241, 0.0502948}, {"ma6", 6, 2., 0.517241, 0.0138588}, {"swhl", 
  11, 28.95, 0.625, 0.0613707}, {"scst", 17, 135.283, 0.576923, 
  0.182524}, {"sfin", 7, 21.6667, 0.576923, 0.0263368}, {"agr", 4, 
  14., 0.454545, 0.0100853}, {"ma7", 8, 3.86667, 0.416667, 
  0.0577164}, {"ma9", 8, 6.5, 0.375, 0.149746}, {"ma10", 6, 6.5, 
  0.384615, 0.0731149}, {"srtl", 8, 17.6167, 0.483871, 
  0.0613707}, {"str1", 6, 14., 0.384615, 0.0629248}, {"sbus", 9, 43.2,
   0.483871, 0.0955785}, {"ma1", 4, 14., 0.319149, 
  0.0366005}, {"ma15", 2, 0.333333, 0.3, 0.00725712}, {"stel", 3, 0., 0.333333, 0.0766315}};

community={{"min", "scst", "ma7", "ma9", "ma10", "srtl"}, {"sfin", "str1", 
  "sbus", "ma15", "stel"}, {"segw", "ma6", "swhl"}, {"agr", "ma1"}};
```

This code:

```
Column[Table[
   {filteredData = 
     Select[centralityTable, MemberQ[community[[i]], #[[1]]] &];
    TableForm[filteredData, 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"\nCommunity " <> ToString[i], 
        "Degree\nCentrality", "Betweenness\nCentrality", 
        "Closeness\nCentrality", "Eigenvector\nCentrality"}}]}, {i, 
    Length[community]}
   ] // Flatten]
```

generates:

[image]

My question: How can I elegantly make a single table without repetition of the column names and separating individual tables with a little empty horizontal space to differentiate individual tables from each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, TableForm is not very flexible. Therefore, you have to insert the spaces by hand:

```
space[x_] = {Prepend[Table[" ", {4}], x]};
tab = Join[centralityTable[[;; 6]], space["Community 2"], 
   centralityTable[[7 ;; 11]], space["Community 3"], 
   centralityTable[[12 ;; 14]], space["Community 4"], 
   centralityTable[[14 ;;]]];
TableForm[tab, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"\nCommunity 1", "Degree\nCentrality", 
    "Betweenness\nCentrality", "Closeness\nCentrality", 
    "Eigenvector\nCentrality"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the code. Is there a way to substitute each community as a group in "tab" above. I wanted to use `Map` each community as a group rather than selecting elements from a list.

Comment: Try to make a grid or table of each group. And then insert this group as an element in a grid or table.